# Show Sign in with Apple ID Pop up in WKWebView same as its shown in Safari in Swift

Tags: swift, webview, safari, wkwebview, apple-id

I am working with a simple URL which when opened in **Safari** and if I select "Sign in with Apple" it shows me a pop up window like below screenshot

[image: Sign in with Apple on Safari Browser]

Now when I use this URL in WebView and select "Sign in with Apple" it doesn't show the pop up.

Need help.